# Jsoup: select() returns empty when it shouldn't

Tags: java, css-selectors, html-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to select the infobox on Wikipedia's Google entry page: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google

So, I call:

```
contentDiv = document.select("div[id=content]").first();
```

Which works as expected, then I do:

```
Elements infoboxes = contentDiv.select("table[class=infobox]");
```

Then I check `infoboxes.isEmpty()` and I am stunned to discover that it is empty!

I checked and verified that the element `contentDiv` contains the following:

```
<table class="infobox vcard" style="width: 22em;" cellspacing="5">
```

So, why does `contentDiv.select("table[class=infobox]")` return empty???

**UPDATE**: I tested the above with `contentDiv.select("table[class=infobox vcard]")` and it works fine! This is weird since I know that unlike the `table.infobox.vcard` notation which only selects the **exact** multiclass element, `table[class=infobox]` should select all tables that have *at least* `infobox` in their listed classes.

BTW, I tested the code, with [a different Wikipedia entry](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple), containing:

```
<table class="infobox biota" style="text-align: left; width: 200px; font-size: 100%;">
```

And that `contentDiv.select("table[class=infobox]")` behaves exactly as expected, returning that table element as the first item in `infoboxes`.

Any idea why the inconsistency? What could explain this odd behavior?

Is it possible that I just stumbled on a Jsoup bug?

(I'm using jsoup-1.5.2, not the latest but I don't need HTML5 support and for various reasons I can't upgrade immediately to the latest 1.6.1).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`[attributename=attributevalue]`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#matching-attrs) selector is an **exact** match. This is specified in [CSS selector spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#matching-attrs) (emphasis mine):

> `[att=val]`
>           Match when the element's "att" attribute value is **exactly** "val".

You want to use the [`[attributename~=attributevalue]`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#matching-attrs) instead:

```
Elements infoboxes = contentDiv.select("table[class~=infobox]");
// ...
```

or, better actually, the [`.classname`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html) selector:

```
Elements infoboxes = contentDiv.select("table.infobox");
// ...
```

#### See also:

- [CSS selector spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) - [attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#matching-attrs) - [class selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html)
- [Jsoup selector cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)
- [Jsoup `Selector` API](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)

---

As to your test with different Wikipedia entry, I can't reproduce this. But I can tell that this page contains another `<table class="infobox">` which must be the one you're actually retrieving.

Comment: I must be an idiot: I have been paying attention all that time to the fundamental difference between the `tag.["class=classname"]` (**exact** match) notation vs. the  `tag.classname` (non-exact) notation, yet I swapped them, then wasted too much time figuring out what's happening. +25.